# Order by on extra field (linker table) with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to know how can I order an extra field on belongsToMany/belongsToMany link ?

I have three tables :

> Courses, Sections, CoursesSections

I try this, but it doesn't work :

```
db.Course.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Section,
            as: "sections",
            through: {
                attributes: ["position"],
            },
        },
    ],
    order: [["CoursesSections.position", "DESC"]],
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    return response.dataValues.sections
})
```

> Migration linker table, with 2 foreign key and 1 extra field :

```
return queryInterface.createTable("CoursesSections", {
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    fk_course_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: "courses",
            key: "id",
        },
    },
    fk_section_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: "sections",
            key: "id",
        },
    },
    position: {
        defaultValue: 0,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
})
```

> Course model :

```
Course.associate = (models) => {
    models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Section, {
        as: "sections",
        through: "CoursesSections",
        foreignKey: "fk_course_id",
        otherKey: "fk_section_id",
    })
}
```

> Section model :

```
Section.associate = (models) => {
    models.Section.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
        as: "courses",
        through: "CoursesSections",
        foreignKey: "fk_section_id",
        otherKey: "fk_course_id",
    })
}
```

**Edit :**

I tried with this :

```
order: [["position", "DESC"]],
```

But I have an error message :

```
"message": "Unknown column 'courses.position' in 'order clause'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix that with this :

```
order: [[Sequelize.literal("position"), "ASC"]],
```